# Does C allow opening two files read only?

Tags: c, file

Title is pretty much self-explanatory. I googled on the web and SO, and not found a satisfactory enough answer. Example:

```
FILE* oneFile = fopen( file, someflags);
FILE* sameFile = fopen( file, someflags);
```

Comment: That's not really in the province of the C language, but depends more on what the OS will allow. (But I cannot offhand think of an OS that doesn't allow multiple simultaneous readers of a disk file).

Comment: Did you try it? You'd have an answer in less time than it took you to write the question.

Comment: I have tried it before, but it crashed. It seems that something else was making the program crash, not opening a file twice, and I fixed that "else" without noticing. It does works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C has nothing to do with it. It's all about your operating system underneath. C has no opinion.